# Prevent access to Admin menu items at Wordpress backend

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to hide and restrict access to some Admin menu items at Wordpress backend for all users except Administrator who is the site owner.

1. Thos Admin menu items have the followings URLs:

   ```
    https://www.mysite1.com/wp-admin/edit.php
    https://www.mysite1.com/wp-admin/tools.php
    https://www.mysite1.com/wp-admin/options-general.php
    https://www.mysite1.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpcf7
    https://www.mysite1.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=acf-field-group
    https://www.mysite1.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=menu-image-options
    https://www.mysite1.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=revslider
   ```

To hide those menu items from those who are not Administrator, I use the following codes in functions.php:

```
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'hide_admin_menu_items' );
    function hide_admin_menu_items() {
      $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
      if ($current_user->ID != 1) {
        remove_menu_page('edit.php');                 // Posts      
        remove_menu_page('wpcf7');                    // Contact Form 7
        remove_menu_page('tools.php');                // Tools
        remove_menu_page('options-general.php');      // Settings
        remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=acf-field-group');          // ACF plugin
        remove_menu_page('menu-image-options');       // Menu image plugin
        remove_menu_page('revslider');               // Revslider plugin
      }
    }
```

The above codes work very well as intended.

2. To prevent access to the above pages or URLs, here are codes in functions.php:

   ```
    // Prevent access to Admin menu items
    add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'prevent_admin_access' );                          // Posts
    add_action( 'load-wpcf7', 'prevent_admin_access' );                            // Contact form 7 plugin - Not working
    add_action( 'load-tools.php', 'prevent_admin_access' );                        // Tools
    add_action( 'load-options-general.php', 'prevent_admin_access' );             // Settings
    add_action( 'load-acf-field-group', 'prevent_admin_access' );                 // ACF plugin
    add_action( 'load-menu-image-options', 'prevent_admin_access' );         // Image menu plugin - Not working
    add_action( 'load-revslider', 'prevent_admin_access' );                  // Rev slider plugin - Not working

    function prevent_admin_access() {
     // $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
     // if ($current_user->ID != 1) {
        // dump and exit user id
        var_dump($user_ID); exit;

        if ( $user_ID != 1 ) {
            wp_die("You are not pwermitted to access this page!");
            exit();
        }
    }
   ```

The above codes dont work for some plugins; they dont restrict access to those who are not Administrator. I use this guide as a reference:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113322/remove-menu-items-from-admin-page-and-limit-capabilities

What is the correct way of coding, for example,

```
    Page/URL: https://www.mysite1.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpcf7
```

I use wpcf7 as the page for Contact form 7 plugin which does not work:

```
    add_action( 'load-wpcf7', 'prevent_admin_access' );
```

What is the correct page for Contact form 7 plugin should be used in the above codes?

Very appreciate any help.

Comment: `global $user_ID` does not seem to be in the docs... https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables could this be the root of your problem... try `var_dump($user_ID); exit;` after `global $user_ID` to confirm issue 

Comment: Hi joshmoto, both global $user_ID and $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); are working. Otherwise, other codes in the second part (2) wont work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an updated answer below, please read comments below so you know what is happening...

You will notice in my code comments which cases that I have tested and which cases I have not..

I don't have have plugins `wpcf7`, `menu-image-options` and `revslider` installed so it's hard for predict how these plugin edit screens work.

Hopefully the logic of how I've presented my php code below might give you a better insight in how to accomplish your problem via a single function.

If you still having problems, please get back to me.

**Updated code below...**

```php
// add action to admin init to dedicate access
add_action('admin_init', 'prevent_admin_access');

/**
 * if $user_id is not 1 then hide specific admin menu items
 * and prevent access to specific admin php pages
 * @return void
 */
function prevent_admin_access() {

    // global $user_ID var
    global $user_ID;

    // if $user_ID is not 1
    if ($user_ID != 1) {

        // remove posts from wp admin menu
        remove_menu_page('edit.php');

        // global $pagenow
        global $pagenow;
        
        // prevent admin access to specific php pages (tools, options-general, admin, edit)
        // switch case for $pagenow var
        switch ($pagenow)
        {
            case 'tools.php':
                // if $pagenow is tools.php die and exit message
                wp_die('You are not allowed to access the Tools page.');
                break;

            case 'options-general.php':
                // if $pagenow is options-general.php die and exit message
                wp_die('You are not allowed to access the Options General page.');
                break;

            case 'admin.php':
                // if $pagenow is admin.php...

                // get $page url var param from admin.php page
                $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : false;

                // switch case $page
                switch ($page)
                {
                    case 'wpcf7':
                        // if $page is wpcf7 die and exit message
                        wp_die('You are not allowed to access the Contact Form 7 page.');
                        break;

                    case 'menu-image-options':
                        // if $post_type is menu-image-options die and exit message
                        wp_die('You are not allowed to access the Menu Image Options page.');
                        break;

                    case 'revslider':
                        // if $post_type is revslider die and exit message
                        wp_die('You are not allowed to access the Revolution Slider page.');
                        break;    

                    default:
                        // return if no $page match
                        return;
                }

                // break out when done if ever necessary
                break;

            case 'edit.php':
                // if $pagenow is edit.php...

                // get $post_type url var param from edit.php page
                $post_type = isset($_GET['post_type']) ? $_GET['post_type'] : false;

                // switch case $post_type
                switch ($post_type)
                {
                    case 'acf-field-group':
                        // if $post_type is acf-field-group die and exit message
                        wp_die('You are not allowed to access the ACF Field Group page.');
                        break;

                    default:
                        // return if no $post_type match
                        return;
                }

                // break out when done if ever necessary
                break;

            default:
                // return if no $pagenow match
                return;

        }

    }

}
```

Anyway, hope this helps you out!

Comment: Dear joshmoto
I have updated the codes as per your instruction. Still does not work.

Comment: URL of plugin which is working: https://www.mysite1.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=acf-field-group

Comment: URLs of the plugins which are not working:         https://www.mysite1.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpcf7
        https://www.mysite1.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=menu-image-options
        https://www.mysite1.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=revslider

Comment: I also corrected my original codes which were messed up in part 2. Please advise how to fix this issue. Cheers

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, only just had time to check it out properly, please see my answer for most up to date solution. I think this is what you are after... more or less. Let me know if you have any problems. I've tested this from my `functions.php` and works very well... (for the tested and working cases)

Comment: Hi Josh, Thank you for great work. I have tested both versions of your codes, the questioned URLs (Contact Form 7, Ajax Search, Slider Revol) are still not working - they are still accessible. There must be a working solution to these? Very appreciate your help.

Comment: I found a post about 9 years ago asking similar thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25743038/prevent-access-to-a-specific-admin-page-wordpress, it means no one can find a correct way to restrict access to certain Admin pages Wordpress?

Comment: this is another link citing the similar issue 3 years ago: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-restric-url-like-wp-admin-admin-phppagexyz/

Comment: OK, seems `load-admin.php` will not work here but we can just scrap all the actions and move the function into our `admin_init` function, contact form 7 is now blocked. See updated answer...

Comment: What are the admin URL's for `menu-image-options` and `revslider`, then I can fix these too.

Comment: Hi, https://www.mysite1.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=menu-image-options, 
 https://www.mysite1.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=revslider

Comment: OK, easy fix, moved `$post_type` cases to the `$page` switch case, i've updated my code.

Comment: Many thanks. I can confirm that your updated codes are working very well. I ll update the whole answer which may be very useful to many people who have similar issues.

Comment: @daro2013 cool man, glad it helped. Can you accept please to close the question. Thanks

Comment: Hi joshmoto,

I have more issues with Custom Post Type list. If you can be helpful, I wont forgot a cup of your coffee. Here are my posts:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/421438/default-wp-post-counts-and-wp-pagination-are-not-correct-for-custom-post-type-po, and

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/421442/how-can-i-enable-checkboxes-for-custom-post-type-posts-on-their-post-list-word

Comment: How can I close the question? I am a newbie here although registered quite a while. Thanks

Comment: There should be a greyed out tick, top left of my answer below the zero, click the tick to approve, and hit the up button to vote if you think answer is well done.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED:

My issue has been fixed by joshmoto. Here is fully working codes.

1. Hide Admin menu items from users who are not Admininstrator of Wordpress:

   ```
      add_action( 'admin_init', 'hide_admin_menu_items' );
          function hide_admin_menu_items() {
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            if ($current_user->ID != 1) {
              remove_menu_page('edit.php');                 // Posts      
              remove_menu_page('wpcf7');                    // Contact Form 7
              remove_menu_page('tools.php');                // Tools
              remove_menu_page('options-general.php');      // Settings
              remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=acf-field-group');          // ACF plugin
              remove_menu_page('menu-image-options');       // Menu image plugin
              remove_menu_page('revslider');               // Revslider plugin
            }
          }
   ```
2. Prevent access to certain Admin pages if users are not Administrators:

   ```
      // add action to admin init to dedicate access
      add_action('admin_init', 'prevent_admin_access');

      /**
       * if $user_id is not 1 then hide specific admin menu items
       * and prevent access to specific admin php pages
       * @return void
       */
      function prevent_admin_access() {

          // global $user_ID var
          global $user_ID;

          // if $user_ID is not 1
          if ($user_ID != 1) {

              // remove posts from wp admin menu
              remove_menu_page('edit.php');

              // global $pagenow
              global $pagenow;

              // prevent admin access to specific php pages (tools, options-general, admin, edit)
              // switch case for $pagenow var
              switch ($pagenow)
              {
                  case 'tools.php':
                      // if $pagenow is tools.php die and exit message
                      wp_die('You are not allowed to access the Tools page.');
                      break;

                  case 'options-general.php':
                      // if $pagenow is options-general.php die and exit message
                      wp_die('You are not allowed to access the Options General page.');
                      break;

                  case 'admin.php':
                      // if $pagenow is admin.php...

                      // get $page url var param from admin.php page
                      $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : false;

                      // switch case $page
                      switch ($page)
                      {
                          case 'wpcf7':
                              // if $page is wpcf7 die and exit message
                              wp_die('You are not allowed to access the Contact Form 7 page.');
                              break;

                          case 'menu-image-options':
                              // if $post_type is menu-image-options die and exit message
                              wp_die('You are not allowed to access the Menu Image Options page.');
                              break;

                          case 'revslider':
                              // if $post_type is revslider die and exit message
                              wp_die('You are not allowed to access the Revolution Slider page.');
                              break;    

                          default:
                              // return if no $page match
                              return;
                      }

                      // break out when done if ever necessary
                      break;

                  case 'edit.php':
                      // if $pagenow is edit.php...

                      // get $post_type url var param from edit.php page
                      $post_type = isset($_GET['post_type']) ? $_GET['post_type'] : false;

                      // switch case $post_type
                      switch ($post_type)
                      {
                          case 'acf-field-group':
                              // if $post_type is acf-field-group die and exit message
                              wp_die('You are not allowed to access the ACF Field Group page.');
                              break;

                          default:
                              // return if no $post_type match
                              return;
                      }

                      // break out when done if ever necessary
                      break;

                  default:
                      // return if no $pagenow match
                      return;

              }

          }

      }
   ```

if you have more restricted Admin pages, just add more case ...

Many thanks